# Windows: error: pg_config executable not found

Tags: django, postgresql-9.3

I added path `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin`. But, still it does **not work**. 
Please, advice me how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

pg_config is the configuration utility provided by PostgreSQL. This utility is used by various applications.

Install PostgreSQL.
Set the path. System Properties > Advanced

```
PATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\;
```

Comment: Thx. I have PostgreSQL installed in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL (win x64 version). But it does not work. Are you advising me install x32?